# Uncore frequency/voltage through adb

Tags: android, arm, adb

I want to study the effects of uncore frequency and uncore voltage on cpu performance for android devices, but I don't know if it is possible.

There is a way to get/change uncore frequency or uncore voltage on android device through adb shell?

Example:

If I want to get my core frequency I can do something like:

```
sudo adb shell
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

Changing core frequency on some core:

```
echo $MYFREQ > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
echo $MYFREQ > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

There is a way to do something like this but with uncore frequency (or voltage)?

Uncore can be defined as the CPU components outside the core but closely associated with it (e.g., the ring interconnect, last-level cache [LLC], and memory controller).

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the hooks available in the mainline linux kernel, as documented [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling) and grepping through the source of 4.6.5, I can't find any sysfs handles or other interfaces that would allow you to adjust, or many cases, view these values.

The android kernel version doesn't add any additional capabilities here - the same sysfs based interface is available there.

So on android-linux and x86 based linux the answer is the same - the bios needs to provide hooks to allow these modifications. Adjusting the bios settings on android is tougher than a 'normal' computer, as the settings are nearly always stored in the bootrom. You'd need to find a technology specific bootrom modification tool, or a custom ROM, that incorporated the settings you'd like to change.